# commands at ubuntu shutdown

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

How to execute one or more commands and scripts when ubuntu shutdown? Is there any script like /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc at system starting? 
I know linux shutdown may have many causes, in addition to dealing with the kill signal, where can I get for this reason?

Comment: the question is confusing because of the sub-question.  /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc don't get run at system startup, but rather at user login and shell startup.  so, do you mean user logout (which would be ~/bash_logout as susggested in John Laine's answer)?  or do you actually mean system shutdown, which would mean you're looking for scripts that are analagous to those found in /etc/init.d ... and for which there are such scripting options.

Comment: @Carina, what are you looking for with respect to details?  Details on what the cause of a given system shutdown was or details on how to add hooks to shutdown to execute commands?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any script like /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc at system starting?

The SysV Init scripts (`/etc/init.d/*`) are invoked at startup.  A trivial/easy way to invoke some activity at system startup is to put it into `/etc/init.d/local` (`/etc/rc.local` for some other distros).  See also: [RcLocalHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RcLocalHowto).

> How to execute one or more commands and scripts when ubuntu shutdown?

It sounds as if you want to create a real init script that gets `start`ed on entering runlevels X-Z and `stop`ped on exiting them.  See also: [UbuntuBootupHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).

> I know linux shutdown may have many causes, in addition to dealing with the kill signal, where can I get for this reason?

To do this noninteractively is not straightforward.  You can grep through the system logs, looking for indications from `shutdown`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a ~/.bash_logout file that executes when you log out of Ubuntu 11.04
I am not sure, but assume there is a similar script in 10.04
Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it is the same script ~/.bash_logout in 10.04 also.

Comment: This is useful advice, but not exactly what OP asks.  User logout is not the same as system shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your script in /etc/rc0.d (for halt) and /etc/rc6.d/ (for reboot). Make sure script has executable permission.

There is differents run level :
* 0 System Halt
* 1 Single user
* 2 Full multi-user mode (Default)
* 3-5 Same as 2
* 6 System Reboot

Run level 0 is the system halt condition. When run level 0 is reached all scripts in /etc/rc0.d are exectute.

Run level 6 is used to signal system reboot. This is the same as run level 0 except a reboot is issued at the end of the sequence instead of a power off.

If you want to execute your script on hibernate or on sleep, put your script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/

This is a example of script :

```
 #!/bin/sh

WLANSTATUS=`cat /sys/class/ieee80211/phy*/rfkill*/state`
test -z $WLANSTATUS && exit 1

case $1 in
    hibernate)
      # Do something before hibernate
        ;;
    suspend)
      # Do something before sleep
        ;;
    thaw)
      # Do something after hibernate
        ;;
    resume)
      # Do something after sleep
    if [ $WLANSTATUS = 0 ]; then
        echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/asus_laptop/wlan    
    elif [ $WLANSTATUS = 1 ]; then
        echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/asus_laptop/wlan
    fi
        ;;
    *)  echo "somebody is calling me totally wrong."
        ;;
esac
```

Have fun !